# Problems with armature not working with head parts

Tags: modeling, armature

i am currently having problems with my character model. I have added a rig to him and his legs and arms work fine: [image: armature legs and arms movement] except the head, the head does this:
[image: character armature head movement]

The whole body was made of separate parts and i object->joined them. I also did some booleans for the chest part of the body where i union'd legs, arms and the head. I am kind of new to blender so any help is very appreaciated. Here is the file: https://www.mediafire.com/file/ydpb1sg1x2ojcr7/stylized_character.blend/file

Answer (score 1):

1. if i look at your character's mesh...

[image]

that's really bad mesh. Maybe you should watch some tutorials about how a mesh should look like.

2. spine.006 is the name of your head's bone. So if you check the vertex group with the same name in weight paint mode you will see:

[image]

dark blue means: won't be affected by your bone

so toggle to x-ray, go to edit mode, select and tap on assign like this:

[image]

but honestly: watch some basic beginner rigging tutorials so that you know what you are doing. That's a very (!) basic question and if you don't know how to weight paint or check your weight paint - you shouldn't do character rigging...

Comment: Thank you very much, somehow I didn't think of weight paint, probably because it was very late, and about the horrendous mesh, I was just trying to somehow fix it by playing around with subdivide and unsubdivide and it got to a point of it looking like this where I just decided to seek for help. But still thank you :).